# Brick-Breaker in C - incrementing rows of bricks issue

Tags: c, function, for-loop, computer-science

I'm trying to re-create brickbreaker using C and the Stanford Portable Library (SPL). The goal of my initBricks function is to add 5 ROWS of bricks with 10 COLUMNS in each row (50 bricks total). When I run this code my window only has 1 ROW of 10 bricks. For some reason it won't output the 4 other rows. I don't see where I went wrong in my code. I'm incrementing the y coordinate (0, 0 is top left of the window) by 40 after each row is created.

```
// number of rows of bricks
#define ROWS 5

// number of columns of bricks
#define COLS 10

// height and width of bricks
#define BRICK_H 7.5
#define BRICK_W 35

// initializes window with grid of bricks
void initBricks(GWindow window)
{
    // set initial brick coordinates
    int x_coord = 2;
    int y_coord = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        // Create 10 columns of bricks
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            // create a brick
            GRect brick = newGRect(x_coord, y_coord, BRICK_W, BRICK_H);
            setFilled(brick, true);
            setColor(brick, "RED");
            add(window, brick);

            // increment x coordinate for column spacing
            x_coord += 40;
        } 
        // increment y coordinate for row spacing
        y_coord += 40;  
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can understand `x_coord += 40;` (ideally `x_coord += BRICK_W + MORTAR_T;`) but not `y_coord += 40;`.

Comment: You never reset your xcord, I suspect all the bricks on the remaining layers are being placed outside of your view port

Comment: @RyanS sorry I answered at same time.

Comment: thanks guys i re-compiled with the x coord being initiated inside the first for loop and works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reset you `x_coord` variable in your outer for loop  so at the end of the first row, your `x_coord` is 202 and that's where it starts writing the next row which may be out of your window. simply adding `x_coord = 2;` after `y_coord += 40;` should fix it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {


       for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            // create a brick
            GRect brick = newGRect(x_coord, y_coord, BRICK_W, BRICK_H);
            setFilled(brick, true);
            setColor(brick, "RED");
            add(window, brick);

            // increment x coordinate for column spacing
            x_coord += 40;
        } 
        // increment y coordinate for row spacing
        y_coord += 40;  
        //reset c coordinate
        x_coord = 2;

    }
```

Comment: such a small mistake yet i couldn't see it! Breaks are underrated lol. thanks @Dom much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the X-coordinate for each row.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    // Create 10 columns of bricks
    int x_coord = 2;                   // <---- move line down to here
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the problem is the X coordinate. You can fix it by moving the X,Y calculations into the `for` loops

```
void initBricks(GWindow window)
{
    int row, col, x, y;

    for ( y = 10, row = 0; row < ROWS; row++, y += 40 )
        for ( x = 2, col = 0; col < COLS; col++, x += 40 )
        {
            GRect brick = newGRect(x, y, BRICK_W, BRICK_H);
            setFilled(brick, true);
            setColor(brick, "RED");
            add(window, brick);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to initialize y co-ordinate in the body of outer loop.
Because every time when you reach to next row y coordinate want to go back its initial position.

```
// number of rows of bricks
#define ROWS 5

// number of columns of bricks
#define COLS 10

// height and width of bricks
#define BRICK_H 7.5
#define BRICK_W 35

    // initializes window with grid of bricks
    void initBricks(GWindow window)
    {
        // set initial brick coordinates
        int x_coord = 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
        int y_coord = 10;
            // Create 10 columns of bricks
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                // create a brick
                GRect brick = newGRect(x_coord, y_coord, BRICK_W, BRICK_H);
                setFilled(brick, true);
                setColor(brick, "RED");
                add(window, brick);

                // increment x coordinate for column spacing
                x_coord += 40;
            } 
            // increment y coordinate for row spacing
            y_coord += 40;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would actually be the other way around. init the x_coord inside the first for loop and init the y_coord outside both for loops